# AWS Cognito Design: How to manage multiple users using multiple user pools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm having the following issue: I have one list of users (the employees on my company) to use several different applications we have developed internally. How should I deal with this users list and the different applications? Should I create only one User Pool (e.g. internal-users) and different cognito client applications within this user pool? Or should I create different user pools and replicate the users list in each of them? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a single User Pool and create different App Clients within this user pool each corresponds to your applications. You can then provide different app client ids for each of your client applications.

Depending on your use case, you can have user service which handles CRUD operations (you may have Users db table) and this service may call Cognito API to handle CRUD operations on Cognito.